# UseState updates in react without calling set function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a usestate in the component. Like below,

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
const [ updated, setUpdated ] = useState([]);
```

Now I am storing an array when the component mounts in the data variable

```
useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.arr)
}, []);
```

Now on a click event, I am calling a method that runs some operation.

```
const click = () => {
       const resp = resolveServices([...data]);
       setUpdated(resp);
     }

const resolveServices = (arr) => {
        for(const a of arr) {
            a.ipa_price = a.ipa_price.toFixed(2)
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Now this automatically changes my data state , even when i am not calling setData method.

Any idea why this happens and how to prevent it. I dont want the state to change unless i call setData method.

Below is the sandbox link.

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-greider-4no3d?file=/src/App.js
```

Comment: the callback in `useEffect` is run after the component mounts and hence calls `setData` that is supposed to happen..

Comment: @FullstackGuy No, the data state is changed when i update "updated" state. I know that it will be first updated when the component mounts. But it updates when i run the function and updates the other state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should convert a.ipa_price back to number , because toFixed return string.

```
    const resolveServices = (arr) => {
        for(const a of arr) {
            a.ipa_price = Number(a.ipa_price.toFixed(2))
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Then you are mutating directly `data` object , which is why `data` object is being changed , which is almost always not a good practice. One of the better approaches would be something like this.

```
 const resolve = (arr) => {
    const newArr = [];
    for (const a of arr) {
      newArr.push({
        ipa_price: Number(a.ipa_price.toFixed(2))
      });
    }
    return newArr;
  };
```

Also you can check it by logging data directly after `resolveServices([...data])`.
By doing `[...data]` , you are doing shallow copy.It is not copying the object properties itself.